# Keyboard and Mouse stop working after resuming from suspend-to-ram

Tags: usb, keyboard, mouse, suspend, 19.04

When I use the suspend-to-ram function and then later resume my system, my USB keyboard and mouse no longer work.

If I SSH into my system after resuming, I can see that `lsusb` does not see the keyboard and mouse.

Physically disconnecting and reconnecting the USB devices causes them to start working again.

Is there a way to fix this?

Motherboard: Asus P8P67 Pro

Ubuntu 19.04

USB devices:

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0f39:1086 TG3 Electronics DK2108SZ Keyboard [Ducky Zero]

Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
(MX2 master)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Power on all USB during resume

It's very difficult to isolate what is going on. One good chance of making everything work is with this script that simulates unplugging your IR during suspend and plugging it during resume:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# NAME: custom-xhci_hcd
# PATH: /lib/systemd/system-sleep
# CALL: Called from SystemD automatically
# DESC: Suspend broken for USB3.0 as of Oct 25/2018 various kernels all at once

# DATE: Oct 28 2018.

# NOTE: From comment #61 at: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/522998

TMPLIST=/tmp/xhci-dev-list

case $1/$2 in
  pre/*)
    echo "$0: Going to $2..."
    echo -n '' > $TMPLIST
          for i in `ls /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/ | egrep '[0-9a-z]+\:[0-9a-z]+\:.*$'`; do
              # Unbind xhci_hcd for first device XXXX:XX:XX.X:
               echo -n "$i" | tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/unbind
           echo "$i" >> $TMPLIST
          done
        ;;
  post/*)
    echo "$0: Waking up from $2..."
    for i in `cat $TMPLIST`; do
              # Bind xhci_hcd for first device XXXX:XX:XX.X:
              echo -n "$i" | tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/bind
    done
    rm $TMPLIST
        ;;
esac
```

#### Housekeeping

Create the script with root powers:

- `sudo -H gedit /lib/systemd/system-sleep/custom-xhci_hcd`

Insert text above and save file. Mark script as executable:

- `sudo chmod a+x /lib/systemd/system-sleep/custom-xhci_hcd`

#### Reboot and test

If the script doesn't help remove it with:

- `sudo rm -f /lib/systemd/system-sleep/custom-xhci_hcd`

Comment: Afraid this didn't seem to have any effect :(

Comment: Can you confirm script was running with `journalctl -b | grep custom-xhci` after you resume?